# Several p-values and understanding real relationships

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

I am trying to solve following exercise:
Suppose I have 500 chemicals for affecting the bacteria growth. My null hypothesis is that applying chemical or not doesn't have any effect on bacteria growth. And then suppose that 50 of these compounds have p-values smaller than 0.05 and their p-values are statistically independent.
Question :How can I estimate expected the proportion of  these 50 compound which shows actually no effect on bacteria growth? How can I approach this problem or which method do I need to check to understand this?
I understand it is related to type 1 error where null is true we reject it but how can I apply this to this problem

Comment: It is extremely difficult, if not impossible, for p-values developed from a common set of data to be independent.  That assumption makes this sound like a textbook problem.  Could you tell us *exactly* what the problem asks?

Comment: @whuber Out of these 500 compounds, there are 50 of them with p-value smaller than or equal to 0.05. I am supposed to find a reasonable estimate of the expected proportion of these 50 compounds that are actually showing no effect on the growth of bacteria. This is the exact question. Give the expected proportion and name which method you apply. It is a question under the subject 'Multiple Testing' if it helps

Comment: This has a range of correct answers, depending most strongly on (a) the nature of the null and alternative hypotheses; (b) the power of the test; (c) the distribution of effect sizes; and (d) exactly what you mean by "shows actually no effect."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You observe $50$ positive test results. Let $X$ be the number of true positives. And $50-X$ is the number of false positives.

You need to estimate the ratio of the two above numbers, which is effectively estimating $X$, which is more intuitive/easy to work with.

Let's assume that there are no false negatives, or that their effect on the estimate is negligible.

Then the number of negatives is $500-X$. You can get to an answer with the following steps

- Describe the probability of observing $50-X$ false positives among the $500-X$ negatives as function of $X$
- The above result for the probability can be seen as a likelihood function as well. Compute the maximum of this function.
- Now you have the maximum likelihood.

Quick result. You would roughly expect around 25 false positives among the more or less 500 negative cases (they are not all positive but it is close). So among the 50 positive you have roughly half of them that are false positive.

Comment: How can I describe the probability of observing $50-X$ false positives among the $500-X$ negatives? I didn't understand the first step

Comment: @Mrnobody Each individual negative case has a 0.05 probability to be observed as a (false) positive case. For multiple negative cases you can model this as a binomial distribution.

Comment: okay that makes sense thank you very much

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I can't explain why, but I have an aversion against gold medals. So I tend to work against them. Since there is a gold medal here for 600 upvotes, I stopped upvoting. Yeah, that kind of counter-intuitive response might not have been imagined by the people that created this incentive for more responses. You should also see my statistics for visiting this website, it is almost every day except when I am getting close to 100 days. I will make a question about that how likely it is that somebody visits the website 1592 days within 5 years without 100 of them being consequitive.

Comment: Anyway the voting system is a broken system. There are a lot of examples of this. Old questions or question that were at some time 'hot network question' had a lot of votes on answers and latecomers that answer do not get the same amount of votes. The answers from me on which I got most of votes are far away from the answers that are most interesting. It is mostly that these answers were poster on more popular answers.

Comment: I see you've got 1 gold medal ... I was close to 2000 days consecutive, but it was broken because of some serios vacation this christmas!

Comment: Damn you @carl for getting me that gold medal.

Comment: To be honest, I do somehow care about the votes, and as a consequence I start posting mostly answers to popular questions (I am not sure but I might currently be the biggest bounty hunter). While, I am doing this I also regard this as a bad behaviour, but I still do it anyway. Those more popular questions are not always 'deserved'. The only way that I can defend myself is that I am also posting to less popular questions. Anyway, 'popularity' is what is important here, and not just here but also science and publications of science in general. I hate it and it kills my product.

Answer (score 0):

If the test statistic is continuous and exact, then
the distribution of the P-value under the null hypothesis is $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$ Often one rejects $H_0$ at the 5% level, if the P-value is
below $0.05.$

However, ***a large P-value of $0.8$ does not make $H_0$ "more true" than a smaller P-value of $0.4.$*** Either way, we simply do not reject $H_0.$

Consider a normal sample of size $n = 20$ for which we use a one-sample t test to test $H_0: \mu=100$ against $H_a: \mu \ne 100,$ where $\mu=100$ is the true population mean. the significance level is
$\alpha = 0.05.$

```
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(20, 100, 15),
                       mu=100)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dunif(x), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
 abline(v=.05, col="red", lwd=4, lty="dotted")
```

The figure below shows the uniform distribution of the P-value. The area of the left-most histogram bar is the significance level. [See the note at the end for the non-uniform distribution of a P-value when the test statistic is discrete or approximate.]

[image]

Nevertheless, a P-value that is very large (say above $0.95)$ may be a warning that the model
is somehow wrong: data not randomly sampled, wrong test, or (as below) ill-formed null and alternative hypotheses.

```
set.seed(420)
x = rnorm(20, 130, 15)
t.test(x, mu = 100, alte="less")

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 9.3716, df = 19, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: 
 true mean is less than 100
95 percent confidence interval:
     -Inf 133.7268
sample estimates:
 mean of x 
  128.4733
```

*Note:* The Wilcoxon signed-rank test is based on ranks (introducing discreteness) and may use some approximations. So the distribution of the p-value under the null hypothesis is not uniform--even though
the significance level is nearly 5%.

```
pv = replicate(10^5, 
wilcox.test(rnorm(20, 100, 15),
                      mu=100)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.04938
hist(pv, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dunif(x), add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
 abline(v=.05, col="red", lwd=4, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!